# App not compatible with buildpack using GOLANG

Tags: go, heroku

it keep showing me that

```
    Using buildpack: heroku/go
    App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/go.tgz
```

when I try to run `git push heroku main`

Even though I got `go.mod` at the same directory , I've tried adding `procfile` and `heroku.xml` just to make it similar to the example of [go-getting-started](https://github.com/heroku/go-getting-started) .

I can run `heroku local` and get the expecting behavior on local.

what can I do?

**EDIT**

here is my project architecture:

```
backend    - db 
           - model 
           - router
           - vendor
           - .env
           - .env.example //since it is a group project at school, this file is an instruction to help my teammate set up their .env
           - db_create.sql //the ".sql"s are scripts to build/manipulate our database 
           - db_delete.sql
           - db_show.sql
           - go.mod
           - go.sum
           - heroku.yml
           - main.exe
           - main.go
           - procfile
```

Comment: What does your project structure look like?

Comment: I'll edit it in my origin post, appreciate any kind of help!!!

Comment: Which directory is the root of your project? Is your `.git/` folder _in_ `backend/` or is `backend/` inside your repository?

Comment: (This is not your current problem, but note that `procfile` ≠ `Procfile`. If you wish to use a `Procfile` it _must_ be named exactly that.)

Comment: ... I swear I did anything previously but when I run ```git init``` and recommit to heroku it just works.